# How can I fix bracket vs dot notation Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The problem is very simple and I think the code below explain better

//The directive

```
.directive('special', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.on('focus', function(){
                element.removeClass('error-form');

                scope.$apply(function(){
                    alert(attrs.personal); //prints out 'INVALID_NAME'
                    scope.errors.INVALID_NAME = false; //updates as I'd like
                    scope.errors[attrs.personal] = false; //Should do the same as above but isn't
                });

            });
        }
    };
})
```

//The code in the field (html)

```
personal="'INVALID_NAME'"
```

I'd like to use the bracket notation coz it will be a reusable directive that I have to use on a lot of fields. But it is not working. What Am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Looks like you've got an extra layer of quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of the variable `attrs.personal` has an extra pair of quotes. Change it to

```
personal = "INVALID_NAME"
```

and it will work.

Comment: Thanks.. need to sleep more :/